# Is organised convoy driving behind a snowplough common anywhere outside Norway?

Tags: driving, winter, snow

Last Sunday I was driving on the [European route E10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_route_E10) and we had to pass the *Bjørnfjell* pass at the border between Norway and Sweden.
In principle the Bjørnfjell road is open all year, but may be closed due to bad weather, as reported by [vegvesen.no](http://www.vegvesen.no/Trafikkinformasjon/Reiseinformasjon/Trafikkmeldinger) on the Norwegian side and [trafikverket.se](http://trafikinfo.trafikverket.se/LIT/#url=Meddelanden&func=messageSearch&value=%7BcountyNos%3A%2225,24,22,23,21,20,17,18,19,3,2,4,14,5,13,6,8,9,7,10,12%22,selectedMsgTypes%3A%22road%22%7D) on the Swedish side.
This was the sight at we approached the road:

[image: waiting for the snowplough to pass Bjørnfjell]

Now, it looks like the road is closed.
However, the Norwegian road authority in this case chooses a hybrid between closing and opening the road, a hybrid that does not exist in Sweden: [*kolonnekjøring*](http://www.vegvesen.no/Trafikkinformasjon/Trafikksikkerhet/Vinterkjoring/Kolonnekjoring) or organised *convoy driving*.
In a nutshell, this means that the snowplough drives back and forth over the part of the road that may be closed, and the cars drive slowly in a convoy behind the snowplough.
As soon as the last car has passed, the road is closed again, until the next round (I think there is a car from the traffic agency following the last car for safety reasons).
See also [this youtube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zvq_8xXrJXE).

For most roads this occurs as necessary and there is no exact timetable.
In [Finnmark](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Finnmark), however, convoy driving happens [according to a timetable per road](http://www.vegvesen.no/Trafikkinformasjon/Trafikksikkerhet/Vinterkjoring/Kolonnekjoring/Kolonnetider+Midt+Finnmark), a timetable that is adapted to times for ferries, schools, church services, etc.

Does such scheduled or unscheduled convoy driving, as a compromise between closing a road due to bad weather or keeping it open, exist anywhere outside Norway?

Comment: Well, only a fool would pass a snowplow, so it's very common in Canada to see a long line of cars following a snowplow. Waiting somewhere for a snowplow to lead you along a highway, that's a different story.

Comment: @KateGregory Yes, it's the latter I'm talking about.  We were around 30 cars behind the snowplough, and I was among the last.  By the time we were driving there were already significant drifts, so someone coming 5 minutes later would have simply gotten stuck.

Comment: While I couldn't find anywhere else where this happens (Yay Norway! Haha), I found this from Massachusetts which is almost equally cool: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjacnDr_cPY

Comment: Closing this because this sounds like a polling question without an actual travel specific component about any particular country. Interesting trivia though!